# Dates filter tree view

Tags: date, filter, treeview, excel-2007, pivot-table

I'm creating several pivot tables. I've got my data source with a date column (set as Date). When I add the date either as a filter or row/column I get a complete list of all dates instead of a nice tree view by Year / Month / Day.

[image: SO20058595 question examples]

Is anyone able to provide some assistance? I'm tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can group dates for a pivot table filter, you can only do it for a regular filter or for a row/column of a pivot table.

To do it, just add the date field to the row/column of the pivot table and on the table shown, right click on one of the dates and click 'group' or 'ungroup'.

Check this link for more details:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/group-items-in-a-pivottable-report-HP010175903.aspx